# Get value of clicked item in Vuetify multiple select component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have the following v-select in my code:

```
<v-select
    v-if='d.length'
    v-model='ci'
    :items='d'
    item-text='value.name'
    item-value='value.name'
    label='label'
    multiple='multiple'
    height='60'
    small-chips
    single-line
    solo
    @change='itemChanged'
  >
  <template v-slot:prepend-item v-if='multiple && title && d.length'>
    <v-list-tile
      ripple
      @click="action"
    >
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-icon :color="ci.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-list-tile-action>
      <v-list-tile-content>
        <v-list-tile-title>{{title}}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
    <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
    <v-chip v-if="index === 0">
      <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
    </v-chip>
    <span
      v-if="index === 1"
      class="grey--text caption"
    >(+{{ checkedItems.length - 1 }} others)</span>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

It receives its model, items and other defs as props. Model and Items are identical arrays of objects with the following structure:

```
{text: 'text', value: {name: 'foo'}}
```

So essentially all the items are selected when the component is mounted.

Once the user clicks on an item from the list, I want to receive in my `itemChanged` method either the entire object, or at least the value object. For time being I only want to console log the received object:

```
itemChanged(value) {
  console.log('Changed item', value);
}
```

But it prints the entire model array, minus the clicked item

Tried to use `return-object`, tried to change the item-value and change the objects structure - always the same result.

Any ideas how can I get only the clicked item object/value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work, or am I misunderstanding your question? This outputs selected items (as objects) back on the page versus `console.log(...)`.

[CodePen mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/details/rbGLpK)

---

***Edit: (answering your question below) ~~Slot Props~~:*** (not to be confused with 'named slots') essentially allow you to take properties from the child component and use them to render in the parent. [You can read more on scoped slots (also known as 'slot props') here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)

Take the follow code block for example:

```
          <template v-slot:item='data'>
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>
                {{ data.item.firstName }} {{ data.item.lastName }}
              </v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </template>
```

`v-slot:item='data'` - you could use any name you wanted in place of data: `v-slot:item="theItems"` would also work (note: you would then use `{{ theItems.item.firstName }}...`

The reason you have to use `data.ITEM.x` (referring to `ITEM`) is because that is what Vuetify calls that `scoped slot` for `v-select` - [you can read more on that here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#api) .. Hope this helps!

[image]

---

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Object]
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chosenItems: [],
      items: [{
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Smith",
          Age: 44
        },
        {
          firstName: "Sarah",
          lastName: "Martin",
          Age: 32
        },
        {
          firstName: "Derick",
          lastName: "Johnson",
          Age: 39
        },
        {
          firstName: "Mary",
          lastName: "Spitzer",
          Age: 22
        },
        {
          firstName: "Wendy",
          lastName: "Macdonald",
          Age: 57
        },
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    selectedItems: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(item) {
        // Could either emit (so you can use v-model on the parent)
        // or add to array
        this.chosenItems.push(item)
        this.$emit("input", item);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-layout row>
          <v-flex>
            <v-select 
              v-model='selectedItems' 
              label='Select One Or Many' 
              :items="items" 
              item-text="firstName" 
              chips 
              clearable 
              multiple 
              return-object
            >
              <template v-slot:selection='data'>
               <v-chip
                :key="JSON.stringify(data.item)"
                close
                class="chip--select-multi"
                @input="data.parent.selectItem(data.item)"
               >
                 {{ data.item.firstName }} {{ data.item.lastName }}
                </v-chip>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:item='data'>
                <v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-list-tile-title>
                    {{ data.item.firstName }} {{ data.item.lastName }}
                  </v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>
              </template>
            </v-select>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <div class="mt-5">
          <v-layout>
            <v-flex>
              <h3>Chosen Items Will Be Displayed Here:</h3>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <div v-for="(chosen, index) in chosenItems">
            <hr/>
            <div v-for="(eachChosen, i) in chosen">
              {{ eachChosen }}
            </div>
            <hr/><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it's pretty much what I needed, but there are a few things I didn't understand: `v-slot:selection='data'`- what is this `data` value? It's not the entire 'data' object, right? `data.parent.selectItem(data.item)` - what is this `selectItem()` method? Where does it come from? I don't see any definition of it...

Comment: @Igal I have updated my answer with an explanation, as well as useful links to help you understand this. These are called `scoped slots` aka `slot props`.. (not to be confused with `named slots` .. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that helps! Thank you very much! :)